# Large image resizing shows blank

Tags: skiasharp

When resizing a large image (> 6MB, 14034px by 9921px), the process goes through with no errors, but the image itself doesn't show upon save, only the white background canvas.

The code works fine with smaller images.

Is there a limit on how large a file size can be processed?

```cs
    using (SKMemoryStream sourceStream = new SKMemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        using (SKCodec codec = SKCodec.Create(sourceStream))
        {
            sourceStream.Seek(0);

            using (SKImage image = SKImage.FromEncodedData(SKData.Create(sourceStream)))
            {
                int newHeight = image.Height;
                int newWidth = image.Width;

                if (maxHeight > 0 && newHeight > maxHeight)
                {
                    double scale = (double)maxHeight / newHeight;
                    newHeight = maxHeight;
                    newWidth = (int)Math.Floor(newWidth * scale);
                }

                if (maxWidth > 0 && newWidth > maxWidth)
                {
                    double scale = (double)maxWidth / newWidth;
                    newWidth = maxWidth;
                    newHeight = (int)Math.Floor(newHeight * scale);
                }

                var info = codec.Info.ColorSpace.IsSrgb ? new SKImageInfo(newWidth, newHeight) : new SKImageInfo(newWidth, newHeight, SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, SKAlphaType.Premul, SKColorSpace.CreateSrgb());
                using (SKSurface surface = SKSurface.Create(info))
                {
                    using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
                    {
                        // High quality without antialiasing
                        paint.IsAntialias = true;
                        paint.FilterQuality = SKFilterQuality.High;

                        // Draw the bitmap to fill the surface
                        surface.Canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);
                        var rect = new SKRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                        surface.Canvas.DrawImage(image, rect, paint);
                        surface.Canvas.Flush();

                        using (SKImage newImage = surface.Snapshot())
                        {
                            using (SKData newImageData = newImage.Encode(convertToJpeg ? SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg : (codec.EncodedFormat == SKEncodedImageFormat.Gif ? SKEncodedImageFormat.Png : codec.EncodedFormat), 
                                codec.EncodedFormat == SKEncodedImageFormat.Gif || codec.EncodedFormat == SKEncodedImageFormat.Png || !downsampleJpeg ? 100 : 85))
                            {
                                return newImageData.ToArray();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To add, I've done some more testing and tried using SKBitmap to resize the image, but I get error 'Unable to allocate pixels for the bitmap'

Comment: How do you display the image? Just asking because I had similar issue, and only problem was that SkiaSharp SKCanvasView could not be bigger than max OpenGL texture size on system (in pixels).

Comment: Thanks Michael, it shows as a white image no matter how I display it (whether in our software, or in Windows photo viewer). Were you using images as big as this?

Comment: Yes, I had a problem with SkiaSharp drawn image within scroll viewer on Android. On some systems, 4096*4096 is maximum. So making big SKCanvasView is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at this and I see it has to do with the maximum size of the memory buffer. When drawing, skia can only understand memory up to the maximum size of `size_t`.

When running as x86, this is 4,294,967,295 bytes. On my x64 machine, this is significantly larger.

I tried to resize a RGBA image with 46,080x31,320, and it failed when running as x86. This is because skia calculates a value of 5,772,902,400 bytes - which overflows. When running as x64, the resize operation succeeds.

I opened a discussion on the skia forums to see what the developers suggest as a workaround: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-discuss/886WuVcQUGo

Answer (score 0):

I crop the image and display two bitmaps

```
    SKRect display = CalculateDisplayRect(dest, scale * bitmap.Width, scale * bitmap.Height,
                                                          horizontal, vertical);
 SKRect newDest = new SKRect(display.Left, display.Top, display.Right, display.Bottom/2);
                    SKRect newSource = new SKRect(display.Left, display.Top, display.Right, display.Bottom / 2);
                    //canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, display, paint);
                    canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, newSource, newDest, paint);
                    SKRect newDest2 = new SKRect(display.Left, display.Top+ display.Bottom / 2, display.Right, display.Bottom );
                    SKRect newSource2 = new SKRect(display.Left, display.Top+ display.Bottom / 2, display.Right, display.Bottom );
                    //canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, display, paint);
                    canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, newSource2, newDest2, paint);


 static SKRect CalculateDisplayRect(SKRect dest, float bmpWidth, float bmpHeight,
                                           BitmapAlignment horizontal, BitmapAlignment vertical)
        {
            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;

            switch (horizontal)
            {
                case BitmapAlignment.Center:
                    x = (dest.Width - bmpWidth) / 2;
                    break;

                case BitmapAlignment.Start:
                    break;

                case BitmapAlignment.End:
                    x = dest.Width - bmpWidth;
                    break;
            }

            switch (vertical)
            {
                case BitmapAlignment.Center:
                    y = (dest.Height - bmpHeight) / 2;
                    break;

                case BitmapAlignment.Start:
                    break;

                case BitmapAlignment.End:
                    y = dest.Height - bmpHeight;
                    break;
            }

            x += dest.Left;
            y += dest.Top;

            return new SKRect(x, y, x + bmpWidth, y + bmpHeight);
        }
```